# file_exist() not working and stopping all code from being executed underneath it

Tags: php, syntax-error, file-exists

Like The title says, I am stumped. I used this function many times in the past with success but now all of a sudden it will just not work at all. Everything above it will be displayed normally, everything underneath it vanishes. The given file path is correct since the **require** works perfectly fine with the same file.

```
//this works
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/custom/phsh/includes/login.php";

//this doesn't return anything it just stops the code right here
echo file_exist($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/custom/phsh/includes/login.php");
```

Comment: Probably an issue with relative vs absolute path. But without seeing your actual code and  file hierarchy, we're just guessing.

Comment: added some code

Comment: If you run into such an error the next time, please add the full and exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a darn spelling error, I wrote file_exist(); but its supposed to be file_exists();